# call method without parenthesis in python

Tags: python, oop

what modification i would need to do in the below function computeDifference to get result printed in the console, instead of object message.

i know i need to add parenthesis () to call function to get the result printed in the console, but is there any other way to print the result?

```
class Difference1:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__elements = a

    def computeDifference(self):
        self.difference =  max(self.__elements)- min(self.__elements)
        return self.difference

a = [5,8,9,22,2]
c = Difference1(a)
print(c.computeDifference)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make it a *property*

```
class Difference1:
@property
def computeDifference(self):
   ...

print(c.computeDifference)
```

However, I would change the name to *difference*. The idea of a property is that you shouldn't know or care whether the value is computed at that time or is stored as an attribute of the object. See [uniform access principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle).

Answer (score 3):

You could add a magic function:

```
class Difference1:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.computeDifference())
    ...

>>> a = [5,8,9,22,2]
>>> c = Difference1(a)
>>> print(c)
20
```

Comment: I got a '__str__ returned non-string (type int)' error. Not sure why?

Comment: @TomJ updated to use `str` on the integer return value from `computeDifference`